# jquery when function to wait for multiple ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a javascript function which waits for multiple ajax calls and then combines the responses into a single javascript array. I then need to return the array (data) from the function but don't know how I can do it.

Can I have some help on this please.

```
var myCombinedArray = fetchData();

function fetchData() {
    var data = [];
    $.when(fetchThisYearsData(),fetchLastYearsData()).done(function(dataThisYear, dataLastYear){
        data[0] = dataThisYear[0];
        data[1] = dataLastYear[0];
        console.log(data);
    }); 
    return data;
}
```

I have read enough to know that myCombinedArray will be empty because the ajax is asynchronous but I don't know what to do to achive my desired result.

thanks

---

### Update

I've tried to implement the callback but am a bit lost. I am getting an error "callback is not a function".

```
$(function () {
  var myCombinedArray;
  fetchData(function (myCombinedArray) {
        //what to do here?
    });

  console.log(myCombinedArray);
})

function fetchData(callback) {

    $.when(fetchThisYearsData(), fetchLastYearsData()).done(function(dataThisYear, dataLastYear){
        var data = [];
        data.push(dataThisYear[0]);
        data.push(dataLastYear[0]);
        callback(data);
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a callback function which will be called once all the data is populated

```
fetchData(function (myCombinedArray) {
    //do your stuff
});

function fetchData(callback) {
    $.when(fetchThisYearsData(), fetchLastYearsData()).done(function (dataThisYear, dataLastYear) {
        var data = [];
        data.push(dataThisYear[0]);
        data.push(dataLastYear[0]);
        console.log(data);
        callback(data);
    });
}
```

Read More

- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I had a very good read of the link and your post. Why I try to implement the callback I get "Callback is not a function". Can you help me a little bit more. I'm about to modify my post to show updated attempt

Comment: Also can I make var myCombinedArray = fetchData(function (myCombinedArray) {}); . If not how do I get the data into my variable.

Comment: @Richie you can't assign it to a variable like that as when `fetchData` is returned the data from the server is not yet loaded...

Comment: thanks your example helped me figure out what was wrong with my code. And then it all worked for me. This has been a good lesson for me on how to master callbacks